# How to get the time in another location programatically in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

**How can I obtain the time in another UTC location**, or at least **what UTC time value is set in the computer** so I can increase/decrease the current time and obtain what I want?

My specific problem is:

I'm in a specific location, and I want to know what time is in **UK**.

Comment: Possibly check out another post on [Retrieving DateTime from another time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-fx-3-5)

Comment: @Brad Let me take a look at it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the answer. [This article](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/24/timezone-vs-timezoneinfo-in-net/) explains `TimeZoneInfo` and `TimeZone` very well, and it has some examples of converting between times of different timezones.

All you need to know is the *ID* of the *Time Zone* you want to convert to.

An example (*taken from the site*):

```
DateTimeOffset nowDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset newDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
    nowDateTime,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time"));

Console.WriteLine("Now: {0}", nowDateTime);
Console.WriteLine("Now in Hawaii: {0}", newDateTime);
```

prints

`Now: 3/5/2011 6:30:48 PM -08:00`
`Now in Hawaii: 3/5/2011 4:30:48 PM -10:00`

To obtain a list of all the IDs, you can:

- Check on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`
- Query `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();`

Comment: A valid list appear to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149346/what-value-should-i-pass-into-timezoneinfo-findsystemtimezonebyidstring#24460750 with `GMT Standard Time` apparently being the one for the UK (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034923/how-to-represent-the-current-uk-time#4035002).